# foreach loop inside foreach loop or something similair?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I'm using foreach loops to make jPlist's wordpress jQuery plugin work with my archive.php
More specifically Im using it to create the checkbox filters so that users can filter. To do this I have to assign classes to span's that match up with the plugins code so to filters will work.

I got the following code so wordpress will automatically assign the 'vehicle category' (this is an custom taxonomy that can be assigned in the custom post type edit screen) to the span class:
`<span class="vehicle-categories hidden CB-<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'vehicle_categories' ); foreach ( $terms as $term ) { echo $term->slug; } ?>"></span>`
It works great and adds classes like `CB-main-battle-tank` to the span.

Nextup is setting up code for the plugin:

```
<!-- Vehicle Categories -->
            <ul
              class="jplist-group"
              data-control-type="checkbox-group-filter"
              data-control-action="filter"
              data-control-name="vehicle-categories">

              <?php $args = array(
                'orderby'            => 'name',
                'order'              => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty'         => 1,
                'taxonomy'           => 'vehicle_categories'
              );
              $categories = get_categories($args);
              foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                  echo '<li class="checkboxListitem-jPlist">';
                  echo '<input data-path=".CB-'.$cat->slug.'" id="'.$cat->slug.'" type="checkbox"/>';
                  echo '<label for="'.$cat->slug.'">'.$cat->name.'</label>';
                  echo '</li>';}
              ?>
            </ul>
```

That foreach loop causes jPlist to recognize the vehicle category and makes the filters work.
[It creates the following filters: (the above code represents on column of filters)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0mb2zmzyx0nwcax/Screenshot%202014-09-14%2016.00.26.png?dl=0)

So it all works great! BUT the problem is when I add two or more values to the post's taxonomy, this occurs with the product categories. the current post outputs the following code in that situation `CB-diorama-accessoiresstowage-sets` and I need it to be `CB-diorama-accessoires CB-stowage-sets`

So this code needs to be modified, but how?
`<span class="vehicle-categories hidden CB-<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'vehicle_categories' ); foreach ( $terms as $term ) { echo $term->slug; } ?>"></span>`

Comment: `echo 'CB-' . $term->slug;`

Comment: Thanks, thats the first part, but that still results in strings like this: `CB-land-vehiclesCB-main-battle-tank` instead of `CB-land-vehicles CB-main-battle-tank` when two or more categories are selected. How do I add the space after each class name IF >1 category is selected?

Comment: `echo 'CB-' . $term->slug . ' ';`

Comment: Thanks, this works as I expected.But, is there no cleaner way to solve this? because every last item with have a space appended to it so classes will look like `class="CB-like-this "` instead of `class="CB-like-this "` or `class="CB-like-this CB-second-item "` instead of `class="CB-like-this CB-second-item"`. In other words, is there a way to make wordpress recognize if there's only one item, or if it's the last of a series and remove the space?